# Change the index of pandas column timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, series

i have a df in pandas like

```
     time                      lower_boundary    mark_price  
  2022-04-05T02:51:36.147633Z  -116914.699042   17.174680   
  2022-04-05T02:51:41.246010Z  -116746.074569   17.263622   
  2022-04-05T02:51:46.345506Z  -116677.835351   17.371671
```

where time is the index , there is 5 seconds differance between each row. I want one second differance adding to the index column.

```
 time                        lower_boundary                        
2022-04-05T02:51:36.147633Z   -116914.699042
2022-04-05T02:51:37.147633Z    None
2022-04-05T02:51:38.147633Z    None
2022-04-05T02:51:39.147633Z    None
2022-04-05T02:51:40.147633Z    None
2022-04-05T02:51:41.246010Z   -116746.074569
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: the milliseconds don't match. so it's not exactly 1sec interval, right?

Comment: Yes, dont want to care about milliseconds..

Comment: so can we safely drop them?

Comment: Yes it can be dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `date_range` to create a range with frequency of 1 second, then use `reindex`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).floor('S')
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='S'))
```

Output:

```
                            lower_boundary  mark_price
2022-04-05 02:51:36+00:00  -116914.699042   17.174680
2022-04-05 02:51:37+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:38+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:39+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:40+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:41+00:00  -116746.074569   17.263622
2022-04-05 02:51:42+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:43+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:44+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:45+00:00             NaN         NaN
2022-04-05 02:51:46+00:00  -116677.835351   17.371671
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s =['2022-04-05T02:51:36.147633Z', '2022-04-05T02:51:41.246010Z', '2022-04-05T02:51:46.345506Z']
vals = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns = ['val'], index = pd.to_datetime(s).floor('S'))
temp = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='S')
df.reindex(temp)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does this gives the other columns as Nan values?

Comment: Here the timestamp is looking differant, how about keeping the same way

Comment: Something like this print (pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.floor('S').dt.tz_convert(None))

Comment: KeyError: 'time' , 

bcz its in index

Comment: a=pd.to_datetime(df1.index) + pd.to_timedelta(d, unit = 'S')
did this

Comment: I couldnt see the whole df, im seeing only the index..

Comment: df1.index=pd.to_datetime(df1.index) + pd.to_timedelta(d, unit = 'S')
df1

This shows incorrect data in index

Comment: The index is added and columns are mismatched

Comment: Also, please note that: The Z stands for the Zero timezone, as it is offset by 0 from the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Comment: The other columns are changing, they are being ignored.. Like the new timestamp values should have other columns values as None..

Comment: Please check the question again..